# SQL Insert from a <select> element with PHP

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a for that accepts input for information of building units

[image: form]

I am using PHP to get the text that is inputted by users in the form, here is a sample from 'Name' and 'Type' `using $_POST['']` (The rest of the textfields are similar).

```
    <div class="col-md-3">Name</div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lease_name" placeholder="Name"
        value="<?php
          if(isset($_POST['lease_name'])) {
            echo($_POST['lease_name']);
          } ?>">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">Type</div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lease_type" placeholder="Type"
        value="<?php
          if(isset($_POST['lease_type'])) {
            echo($_POST['lease_type']);
          } ?>">
    </div>
```

after the input they are inserted to my SQL database using:

```
public function InsertLease($db, $lease_name, $lease_type, $lease_address, $lease_condition, $lease_description, $lease_price, $lease_floor_area, $lease_lot_area, $lease_furnishing, $lease_bedroom, $lease_bathroom, $lease_parking, $lease_contract, $recstatus, $createddate) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare(
      " INSERT INTO for_lease
          (lease_name, lease_type, lease_address, lease_condition, lease_description, lease_price, lease_floor_area, lease_lot_area, lease_furnishing, recstatus, createddate)
        VALUES
          (:lease_name, :lease_type, :lease_address, :lease_condition, :lease_description, :lease_price, :lease_floor_area, :lease_lot_area, :lease_furnishing, :recstatus, :createddate) "
    );

    $stmt->bindValue(':lease_name', $lease_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':lease_type', $lease_type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':lease_address', $lease_address, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':lease_condition', $lease_condition, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':lease_description', $lease_description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':lease_price', $lease_price, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':lease_floor_area', $lease_floor_area, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':lease_lot_area', $lease_lot_area, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':lease_furnishing', $lease_furnishing, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':recstatus', $recstatus, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':createddate', $createddate, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt->execute();
    $insertId = $db->lastInsertId();

    return $insertId;
  }
```

The text fields are added successfully but my  dropdown list does not, my SQL table just shows an empty column where it should be. (partial screenshot)

[image: 2]

**PS:** my leaseid is auto incremented

Here is my current code for my drop down in the 'Furnishing' field as seen in the screenshot above:

```
<select class="form-control" name="lease_furnishing">
  <option value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['lease_furnishing']) AND $_POST['lease_furnishing'] == 'Bare') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>">Bare</option>
  <option value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['lease_furnishing']) AND $_POST['lease_furnishing'] == 'Partially Furnished') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>">Partially Fitted</option>
  <option value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['lease_furnishing']) AND $_POST['lease_furnishing'] == 'Fully Furnished') ? 'selected' : ''; ?>">Fully Furnished</option>
</select>
```

What seems to be the issue on my code? My initial thoughts is it echos whatever `<option>` is selected using `$_POST[''] == ''`

---

**UPDATE:** This gets triggered once I clicked on my 'Submit' button.

```
  if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'SAVE')
  {
    $lease_name = $_POST['lease_name'];
    $lease_type = $_POST['lease_type'];
    $lease_address = $_POST['lease_address'];
    $lease_condition = $_POST['lease_condition'];
    $lease_description = $_POST['lease_description'];
    $lease_price = $_POST['lease_price'];
    $lease_floor_area = $_POST['lease_floor_area'];
    $lease_lot_area = $_POST['lease_lot_area'];
    $lease_furnishing = $_POST['lease_furnishing'];
    $recstatus = '1';
    $createddate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

      // Update the Post
      $leaseid = $mcProperty->InsertLease(
        $db,
        $lease_name,
        $lease_type,
        $lease_address,
        $lease_condition,
        $lease_description,
        $lease_price,
        $lease_floor_area,
        $lease_lot_area,
        $lease_furnishing,
        $recstatus,
        $createddate
      );

      header("Location: for_lease.php"); die();
    }
```

Comment: can you include the call to `InsertLease()`

Comment: added the call in my question

Comment: view the form source, you will see the value setting in the options is not actually set

Comment: can you elaborate on that?

Comment: view source look at the form code, the value fields are not populated, sellected does not go in that atribute

Comment: you are right, the value fields are empty, this did the trick: <option value="Bare<?php if(isset($_POST['lease_furnishing'])) { echo($_POST['lease_furnishing']); } ?>">Bare</option>